# wrong twoside margin

Tags: margins, double-sided

I am using the twoside margin in a book classes but I have inverse margins.
On odd pages left margin is wider than the right one and viceversa on even pages.

It is a subclasses, I attached it below, It seems to me there is not a possible conflict.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}


\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGINS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setmarginsrb   { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
%\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}

%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
%\markboth{\chaptername
%\ \thechapter. \ #1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \  #1}}

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\thesistitle}[1]{\def\ttitle{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT VARIABLES
%   Fill in the lines below to update the thesis template
%   If you wish to cite each of the variables defined below, look at the
%   section above for the citation command e.g. \examiner{} below is
%   defined as \examname above so you cite it as \examname
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{} % Your thesis title - this is used in the title and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------  
\supervisor{} % You supervisor's name - this is used in the title page
%-------------------------------------------------   
\examiner{} % Your examiner's name - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \examname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} % Your degree name - this is currently used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\authors{} % Your name - this is used in the title page and abstract
%-------------------------------------------------   
\addresses{} % Your address - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \addressnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\subject{} % Your subject area - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \subjectname if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \keywordnames if you want it
%-------------------------------------------------   
\university{\texorpdfstring{\href{} % Your university's URL
                {}} % Your university's name - this is currently used in the title page
                {}}
%-------------------------------------------------   
\UNIVERSITY{\texorpdfstring{\href{http://www.unipd.it (include http://)} % Your university's URL
                {}} % Your university's name in capitals - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\department{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {Department or School Name}} % Your department's name - used in the title page and abstract
                {Department or School Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\DEPARTMENT{\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your department's URL
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your department's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \DEPTNAME if you want it
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\group{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {Research Group Name}} % Your research group's name - this is currently used in the title page 
                {Research Group Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\GROUP{\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your research group's URL
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your research group's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \GROUPNAME if you want it
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\faculty{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {Faculty Name}} % Your faculty's name - this is currently used in the abstract page
                {Faculty Name}}
%-------------------------------------------------                
\FACULTY{\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)} % Your faculty's URL
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}} % Your faculty's name in capitals - this is not currently used anywhere in the template, cite it with \FACNAME if you want it
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

% The default title page, this is not used in this www.latextemplates.com version            
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      {\LARGE by \par}
      \smallskip
      {\LARGE \authornames \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
      {\large degree of \degreename \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large in the \par}
      {\large \facname \par}
      {\large \deptname \par} 
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\Large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE DESIGN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize \UNIVNAME \par} % University name in capitals
    \bigskip
    {\huge{\textit{Abstract}} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    {\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \@title \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by \authornames \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
%\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
%\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Acknowledgements}} \par}\end{center}
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
%\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems to be a (bad) choice by the class itself. The style is definitely not what I consider good, by the way. The package `vmargin` that the class uses is incompatible with some very useful packages. My suggestion is to remove the calls to it and to use `geometry`, changing the margin setup to your taste.

Comment: Yep, now that I'm getting into Tex more deeply I agree with you. The problem is that I have to submit the thesis this week. Can I use the package geometry and mantains the same margins? If I correctly understood I have to "translate" this from vmargin to geometry. \usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb   { 1.5in}  % left margin
               .....         .....    
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep

Comment: Apparently the author of the class thinks that half an inch is needed for the binding. It depends on the type of binding, of course, but it rarely needs more than 1/4 of an inch (6mm). Just swap the left margin with the right margin in `\setmarginsrb` or adjust them as you prefer; just make it up so their sum is still 2.5in

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't switch to another class or at least use `geometry` instead of `vmargin`, a quick way to produce typographically sensible margins is to use `\setmarginsrb` again (with changed parameters for inner and outer margin) in the preamble of your document.

```
\documentclass{book}% `default: `twoside`

\usepackage{vmargin}

% First call of \setmarginsrb (e.g., in a class file)
\setmarginsrb       { 1.5in}% left margin (inner margin for `twoside`)
                    { 0.6in}% top margin
                    { 1.0in}% right margin (outer margin for `twoside`)
                    { 0.8in}% bottom margin
                    {  20pt}% head height
                    {0.25in}% head sep
                    {   9pt}% foot height
                    { 0.3in}% foot sep 

% Second call of \setmarginsrb (e.g., in the document preamble)
\setmarginsrb       { 1.0in}% left margin (inner margin for `twoside`)
                    { 0.6in}% top margin
                    { 1.5in}% right margin (outer margin for `twoside`)
                    { 0.8in}% bottom margin
                    {  20pt}% head height
                    {0.25in}% head sep
                    {   9pt}% foot height
                    { 0.3in}% foot sep 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```